# Unknow expression. SDL related

Tags: sdl

I am learning SDL and  I found this piece of code in the manual:

```
SDL_Rect **modes;
int i;


/* Get available fullscreen/hardware modes */
modes=SDL_ListModes(NULL, SDL_FULLSCREEN|SDL_HWSURFACE);

/* Check is there are any modes available */
if(modes == (SDL_Rect **)0){
printf("No modes available!\n");
exit(-1);
}

/* Check if or resolution is restricted */
if(modes == (SDL_Rect **)-1){
 printf("All resolutions available.\n");
 }
        else{

   /* Print valid modes */
  printf("Available Modes\n");
  for(i=0;modes[i];++i)
    printf("  %d x %d\n", modes[i]->w, modes[i]->h);
}
```

I now that modes is a pointer to an array of SDL_rect but expression:

```
(modes== (SDL_Rect **)0)
```

escapes my reasoning.
What does (SDL_Rect **)0 means?

Answer (score 2):

It's checking if it is a null pointer.

Since it's checking up if it's null, the cast it's not necessary, it could just be:

```cpp
if(modes == 0)
```

or

```cpp
if(modes)
```